# Parsing JsonArray using SBJson Framework in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, parsing, ios7, sbjson

I am getting json data from url as below:

```
{"message":"success","vendors":[{"businessname":"webixion","vendorid":"67","vendor_city":"kakinda"}]}
```

How to retrieve all 'message',businessname','vendorid','vendor_id' values

I am using SBJson Framework in Xcode 5 of IOS 7.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Why would you still be using SBJSon when you can use Apple [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: can u tell me how to use NSJSONSerialization to retrieve json array

Comment: plese search on google first

Comment: It does not seem so, but one may want to use SBJson if you need to do SAX style parsing with JSON. If it is not the case, just use NSJSONSerialization as advised.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have a reason to use SBJSON over the native `NSJSONSerialization`, but the latter is about 5 times faster in my completely unscientific tests.

With NSJSONSerialization, you would do something like this:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/to/file.json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: Although it is a good answer, it is not a good practice to load a `NSData` object from internet using the `dataWithContentsOfURL:`. You should use either [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to have more control over the data retrieval and error handling.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is the shortest way I know, but in a live situation you should `NSURLSession` if possible.